# NPM, Angular-CLI very slow to execute on Windows 7 and 10

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, angular-cli

I have issues with NPM and Angular CLI being slow to execute on Windows 7 & 10. If you open **npm.cmd** from the **%AppData%\npm** folder in your favorite editor you get the following.

```
@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
  "%~dp0\node.exe"  "%~dp0\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" %*
) ELSE (
  @SETLOCAL
  @SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
  node  "%~dp0\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" %*
)
```

If I copy the file contents into a new file, change the last line from

> node  "**%~dp0**\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" %*

to

> node  "**%APPDATA%\npm**\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" %*

and place it in my home directory, the execution time will halve.

Before modification:

[image: windows powershell]

After modification:

[image: windows powershell]

What could be the issue and how could I possibly resolve it? The slowdown is very pronounced when using the angular cli. It takes ages to do anything.

Comment: wich versions of npm or node are you using? Tested `npm -v` on my Windows 10 machine with Node: v8.9.4 and npm: 5.6.0 and got **00:00:02:127**

Comment: Node v9.2.0 and NPM v5.6.0 on my work win 7 machine .. Did you get over 2 seconds? That seems really slow. On my personal machine (mac) it is almost instantaneous.

Comment: just tested the exact same versions on my gentoo box: **0m0.224s** very depressing